# Biquad Filter Optimization

Tags: filters, filter-design, optimization, biquad

I would like to try optimize a bit more the biquad filters indended for RIAA/non-RIAA equalization at low samplerates (44.1/48kHz).

Are there any open source optimization libraries (C, C++ or C#) out there I could examine or even use?

Juha

EDIT: continues in thread [How to improve filter quality at low fs](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29372/how-to-improve-filter-quality-at-low-fs)

Comment: If we start from basics. I've got suggestion to use steepest descent (also called gradient descent) and "genetic search".  Are these suitable methods?

Comment: I think you can get very close to the spec with just two biquad sections. How well does this fit   1: f0=20,   Q=0.1, G=22 (peaking)
2: f0=1050, Q=0.5, G=1.5 (peaking)
3: f0=3000, Q=0.8, G=1.2 (peaking )
4: f0=7000, Q=0.4, G=-17.5 (highshelf)  the values are for audio eq cookbook design equations.

Comment: I didn't check this because of I'm after biquad solution and I already am  able to prepare accurate filter using two sections.